# Embed external html file using iframe in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I'm trying to embed an interactive graph, which is saved as an html file, in a reStructuredText document using `iframe`:

```
.. raw:: html

    <iframe src="filename.html" height="345px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

The html file is in the same directory as my `.rst` file, but the graph does not display, and I'm getting a `file could not be found` error.

However, if I paste the external html file in the `_build/html` directory, the graph displays fine. How do I properly embed this html file, so that the graph is embedded automatically when I `make html`?

[Working example of the thing that I want.](http://rcharts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/create.html#polycharts)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could put the file `filename.html` in your `source/_static` directory. It would then be copied into `build/html/_static`, so you would have to replace the `iframe` attribute by `src="_static/filename.html"`.

Comment: See also https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path

Answer (score 29):

You can also include a file directly:

```
.. raw:: html
   :file: filename.html
```

May not be what you wanted, but may help others coming here from google...